# extracting numbers from a string in a list via regex

Tags: python, regex, list

I've a linear equation and i'm trying to process it in `Python`. This linear equation is in a list.

```
z=['i=(6040.66194238063)+(51.7296373326464*a)+(41.7319764455748*b)+(-193.993966414084*c)+(-215.670960526368*d)+(-531.841753178744*e)+(5047.1039987166*f)+(3925.37115184923*g)+(77.7712765761365*h)']
```

I want to find a way to build a list which contains all the constants.

Comment: Just extract letters [a-z]{1}

Comment: do you know the number of elements to extract?

Comment: Why do you have a single-element list with one big string in it?

Comment: I want all the elements to be extracted.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I did not understand.

Comment: @Ploutox the letters are the variables, the constants are the numbers

Comment: I want to find a way to extract all the constants.

Comment: @blueygh2 ahahah my bad :) try something like this then : -?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
m=re.findall('-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*', z[0])
```

will give you a list `m`:

```
['6040.66194238063', '51.7296373326464', '41.7319764455748', '-193.993966414084', '-215.670960526368', '-531.841753178744', '5047.1039987166', '3925.37115184923', '77.7712765761365']
```

If you want the list as a list of floating point numbers, you can now do:

```
m = [float(x) for x in m]
```

Comment: The negatives are missing.

Comment: sorry about that, fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the constants in a list, the following should do the work:

```
z = ["i=(6040.66194238063)+(51.7296373326464*a)+(41.7319764455748*b)+(-193.993966414084*c)+(-215.670960526368*d)+(-531.841753178744*e)+(5047.1039987166*f)+(3925.37115184923*g)+(77.7712765761365*h)"]
for elem in z:
    num = ""
    cst = []
    for c in elem:
        if c.isdigit() or c =='.' or (c == '-' and not len(num)):
            num += c
        elif len(num):
            cst.append(num)
            num = ""
    print cst
```

This will output:

```
['6040.66194238063', '51.7296373326464', '41.7319764455748', '193.993966414084', '215.670960526368', '531.841753178744', '5047.1039987166', '3925.37115184923', '77.7712765761365']
```

Comment: You forgot negatives (`-193.993`).